# Using pug/jade to iterate over an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Using node with express, I've queried my database and returned an array of objects - verified by console logging the array.

I now need to loop through the array of objects, grab the key/value pairs I need and print them as a list to the html using pug.

Pug's iteration documentation says this:

```
ul
  each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    li= val
```

In my app.js file, this is the code I'm using to render the page:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {storeItems: results});
});
```

In my pug file, I'm using this syntax.

```
.col-6
  ul.list-group
    each storeItem in storeItems
       li.list-group-item storeItem.product_name
```

Running this code generates the following error.

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. It says the error is on this line:

```
each storeItem in storeItems
```

I'm not seeing where I need to declare the length of the array in the pug documentation. What am I missing? I've tried adding .length to the storeItems - generates the same error. I've tried using the = sign after the li which also generates the same error.

[image]

Comment: Not super familiar with Pug, but the docs say to add an = after the element tag
https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html
I wonder if you are missing the  = in 
li.list-group-item= storeItem.product_name
And it's just throwing an error up the stack.

Comment: My best guess would be that storeItems is neither an array or object.  Try hardcoding the value `results`

Comment: @KaysserKayyali I have tried that and it still returns the same error.

Comment: @maioman I had it working fine through ejs and it was iterating very well. But I had to switch to jade/pug for other reasons. In ejs, I used storeItems.length as it has a more traditional js syntax and it worked beautifully.

Comment: Please add yor **console.log(results)** and write in your question what  print of console.log

Comment: updated post with pic of console.log(results)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.col-6
  ul.list-group
    each storeItem in storeItems
       li.list-group-item=  storeItem.product_name // missed **equal to** operator here
```

Comment: as I said in the initial post. I have also tried that. But I did try it again and it returns the same error on the same line.

Comment: I ran typeof and it came back object. So that must be why.

Comment: try Object.prototype.toString.call(array_name), it must be return something like "[object Array]" for arrays. Otherwise, arrays are also treated as objects in javascript hence typeof will return "object" for arrays too.

Comment: I updated the post to put a pic up of what the return db query comes back as.

Comment: @J.G.Sable. Why is your array like [rawdatapacket{..}, rawdatapacket{...} ...] and not [{}],{}..]

Comment: ha. I don't know. That's just the way it came back from the mySQL db.

Comment: @J.G.Sable In javascript you cant have arrays like it, unless rawdatapacket is a function which returns some value. And that too must be something like rawdatapacket({}). Try parsing your database return value and make it array of objects

Comment: like JSON.parse(results)?

Comment: @J.G.Sable.  I mean to convert your DB data to like I said either through iteration or using some other method. I don't know about your db hence can't comment much on that.

Answer (score 0):

As @kaysser-kayyali said, check the =. I had the same exact problem and the = solved the problem:

```
.col-6
    ul.list-group
        each storeItem in storeItems
            li.list-group-item= storeItem.product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the array of returned objects into an object that has a single property whose value is the array of returned objects. In your example, you've stored the array of objects in the array "storeItems". Instead, create an object {storeItems:[your array of objects here]}, and then your iteration should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is change

> =

for

> !{foo}

And change each statement and add the index, I always use this structure, it should work.

Example:

```
.col-6
    ul.list-group
        - console.log(storeItems)
        each storeItem, index in storeItems
            - console.log(storeItem)
            li.list-group-item !{storeItem.product_name}
```